# screen.blit(Lab.image,Lab.rect) AttributeError: type object 'LabClass' has no attribute 'image'

Tags: python

Hi I am working on a new game and I want to test it to fix any problems and make it work. However the python shell keep giving me this message.

screen.blit(Lab.image,Lab.rect)
AttributeError: type object 'LabClass' has no attribute 'image'

I have tried every thing to fix this but I can't. Can soneone pleas help me?
I do know that there could be other problems that I will have to fix but I need help with this problem.

```
import pygame
import time

key1_images = ["clear.png", "key1.png"]
guy_images = ["lab.png", "shock.png"]

class LabClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("lab.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class key1Class(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("clear.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [310,250]


def levelUp():
    levelUp = False
    if levelUp == True:
        level = level + 1
        levelUp = False

def zap():
    guy.image = pygame.image.load("shock.png")
    animate()
    time.sleep(2)
    T_text = font.render("Oh no, you were", 1, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(T_text,[220,320])
    pygame.display.flip()


def key1Kill():
    key1.image = pygame.image.load("clear.png")
    animate()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    zap()

def key1Play():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            score = True
            score()
            choose = True
            choose()
            key1.image = pygame.image.load("clear.png")
            animate()
        else:
            key1Kill()
    if level <5:
        clock.tick(10)
        key1die = True
    if key1die == True and score == False:
        key1Kill()
    else:
        key1die = False
    if level >5 and not 10:
        clock.tick(5)
        key1die = True
    if key1die == True and score == False and choose == False:
        key1Kill()
    else:
        key1die = False
    if level >9:
        clock.tick(3)
        key1die = True
    if key1die == True and score == False:
        key1Kill()
    else:
        key1die = False

def choose():
    choose = True
    if choose == True:
        clock.tick(2)
        key = random.randint(1,3)
        if key == 1:
            key1.image = pygame.image.load("key1.png")
            animate()
            key1Play()
            choose = False



def score():
    score = False
    if score == True:
        pointstest = pointstest + 1
        score = False
    if pointstest == 10:
        levelUp = True
        levelUp()

def getLife():
if level >18 and levelUp == True:
        num = random.randint(1,20)
        if num ==(10, 15, 1, 3, 11):
            lives = lives + 1

def getCoin():
    if levelUp == True:
        num2 = random.randint(1,15)
        if num2 ==(1, 5, 15, 3, 7): 
            coins = coins + 1

def animate():
    screen.blit(Lab.image,Lab.rect)
    screen.blit(key1.image,key1.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()







pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640,640])
coins = 0
lives = 0
level = 1
pointstest = 0
Lab = LabClass
key1 = key1Class

while True:
    animate()
    choose()
    getLife()
    getcoin()
    levelUp()
    score()
```

Comment: This will go better if you tell us some of the "everything" you've tried :)

Comment: Try changing this line `Lab = LabClass` to `Lab = LabClass()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialized `LabClass`.  Change:

```
Lab = LabClass
```

To:

```
Lab = LabClass()
```

This way it can access the `image` variable by doing `Lab.image`.  I recommend taking another look at the [Python Classes Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
Lab = LabClass
key1 = key1Class
```

You are not calling the constructor of these two classes, you probably mean:

```
Lab = LabClass()
key1 = key1Class()
```

Although there seem to be other mistakes (for instance you use the random module without importing it)

Comment: ok thanks and remember I did say that there where other problems that I needed to fix. But I have to test the game befor I can fix them.